# Pass an undefined variable as an optional argument to the function and let it populate it, but only if argument is present

Tags: php, function, pass-by-reference, optional-parameters

In PHP some functions have an optional argument, which when passed is automatically populated inside the function with some value. Obviously function receives it by reference, since its value becomes available in the outer code. How to mimic such pattern manually?

Comment: What do you mean by _"since its value becomes available in the outer code"_? For example, `in_array()` has optional third parameter, but if you'll omit it (false by default) - no variable outside function context will be set to `false` (and that makes no sense or I didn't get that sense properly from your question)

Comment: "Obviously function receives it by reference" Nothing is passed or assigned by reference unless there is an `&`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check if the optional var ist set - you define a default value yourself.

```
function do_something($var1, &$optional_var=0) {
    //do something
    $optional_var = somevalue;
    return;
}
```

Comment: I do not need it to set any value if the argument was not passed in from an outer code, since the operation (complex calculation) is quite costly.

Comment: the argument is always passed. if you don't fill it in your call the default value is passed.